# Where does snmpwalk start if no OID is specified?

Tags: snmp

Where in the SNMP OID tree does `snmpwalk` start if no OID is specified, i.e. `snmpwalk` is started like `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public host`? From `.1.3.6.1.2.1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from doing a network capture, it would seem so:

```
SNMP 84 get-next-request 1.3.6.1.2.1
```

Which is:

```
$ MIBS=+all snmptranslate 1.3.6.1.2.1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2
$ MIBS=+all snmptranslate -Of 1.3.6.1.2.1
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2
```

Confirmed by reading [the source](https://github.com/haad/net-snmp/blob/master/apps/snmpwalk.c#L74):

```
oid             objid_mib[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1 };
[...]
    if (arg < argc) {
[...]
    } else {
        /*
         * use default value
         */
        memmove(root, objid_mib, sizeof(objid_mib));
        rootlen = sizeof(objid_mib) / sizeof(oid);
    }
```

And [the man page](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpwalk.html):

> If no OID argument is present, snmpwalk will search the subtree rooted at SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.